# Google analytics filtering returns no results

Tags: google-analytics

I am tracking a number of events on my site for several weeks and these are accumulating in the GA webpage, as shown in the first image.

[image: GA view]

But in the query explorer, while I can filter on `gs:eventCategory==filters` (and outbound_link), I get no results at all with

[image: failed filter]

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe Review_post does not have a label ? I'm not quite certain but from the top of my head I think the api will omit rows for which requested dimensions are not set.

Comment: genius!!!!!  thanks.....